# Node JS: Where is my POST data?

Tags: node.js, post

I have no lack with sending POST request to node js server. I have a simple request and a simple server.

My server code is:

```
var http = require('http');
var bodyParser   = require('body-parser');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {

console.log(req.body);

res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
res.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(1337, '127.0.0.1');
console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:1337/')
```

my client request code is:

```
var val = JSON.stringify({ city:"SomeCity", name:"MyNameIsHere" });
alert(val);
$.ajax({
     url: 'http://127.0.0.1:1337',
     type: 'POST',
     data: { value:  val},
     success: function(result) {
         alert('the request was successfully sent to the server');}
});
```

So I suppose to get **SomeCity** and **MyNameIsHere** strings in the request body at the node js server, but the req.body field is undefined. Have to say that I open my test.html with request code locally with URL like this:

```
file:///D:/Projects/test.html
```

May be Im blind and overseen something trivial, but I have no idea what:)

Answer (score 2):

> Have to say that I open my test.html with request code locally with URL like this:
>   `file:///D:/Projects/test.html`

You're trying to post cross-domain, which you cannot do in this case.  Serve your HTML over HTTP so that you can make a POST.  If you use your browser's development tools, you will see that the request will never hit your Node.js server (except for a possible pre-flight request for CORS).

Another problem is that you're not actually using `body-parser`.  If you want the post data, you will have to read from `req` like a stream.

Comment: Oh, it is true. I ended up with the adding express to my server code and was able to get my post request on the server side. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You are including "body-parser" in `var bodyParser = require('body-parser');`, but you never actually use it. It won't magically parse the request for you. The default `request` object does not have a `body` property... see [the documentation](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html).

If you want to use the `body-parser` module, you should probably use `express.js` and read the documentation on how to connect it as middleware.

If you want to get the body using the built-in `http` server, you need to consume the `request` object first using something like this:

```
if (req.method == 'POST') {
    var body = '';
    req.on('data', function(data) {
        body += data;
        if (body.length > 1000000) {
            req.connection.destroy();
        }
    });
    req.on('end', function () {
        console.log(req.body);

        res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
        res.end('Hello World\n');
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you - that is what I had missed since Im noob with nodeJS. I added express and was able to get my Post data. Surprisingly bodyparser handle only 100kB request body by default so I changed the limit using its configuration to what I need:  app.use(express.bodyParser(
{
    keepExtensions: true,
    limit: 30*1024*1024      
}
));

Answer (score 0):

Adding express library and bodyparser as middleware did the trick. However I could use the code from [neelsg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1877903/neelsg) answer but working with built-in http server and handling Post data by my own is too burdensome. 
So piece of my working code is here:

```
var express = require('express');
var http    = require('http');
var url     = require('url');
var bodyParser   = require('body-parser');

var app = express();
app.use(express.bodyParser(
{
    keepExtensions: true,
    limit: 30*1024*1024 // lets handle big data  
}
));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded());
```

Bodyparser by default can handle only 100Kb data in the post request, so I had to increase limit using its config options.